# How to convert a number that could ve variable from 0 to 10 digits into an amount format Unix KSH

Tags: shell, unix, formatting, money-format

I'm trying to convert a number that could be variable from 0 to 10 digits into an amount format, I already have a solution for this (while loop all the digits) but someone told me that is much easier using printf command, an example of the format is:

```
AMOUNT_WITHOUT_FORMAT        AMOUNT_WITH_FORMAT
6627492                      66,274.92
772220124                    7,722,201.24
120198                       1,201.98
```

How can I format these values like that?

As I said, I already have a solution but I want to improve it with less code lines.

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code for your actual requirement which works.

```
sed -e 's/..$/.&/g' | sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'
```

EXPLANATION:

1. First sed process matches the last two digits and substitute dot(.) at the front of the matched string.
2. Second Sed is a process of looping to match the three three digits for adding commas to it.

Output:

```
23235235202   
2325245
232,352,352.02
23,252.45
```

I have got this by referring the below link..

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/38397-insert-decimal-point.html

Comment: You are welcome @javier. Can you add the code that you have tried yet .

Comment: Yes sure, I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

From sed one liners

Code:

#add commas to numeric strings, changing "1234567" to "1,234,567"

```
gsed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta'
```

## GNU sed

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'  # other seds
```

# add commas to numbers with decimal points and minus signs (GNU sed)

```
gsed -r ':a;s/(^|[^0-9.])([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})/\1\2,\3/g;ta'
```

Comment: this is the most close answer using sed command, but still need to have the dot to have 2 decimals on it...

Comment: But it doesn't matter, at this point what I can do is cut two last digits and just add comma to the other numbers.

Comment: If the input is 12232.13 then produces 12,232.13. This is the one you ask about? Right? -@Jav

Answer (score 0):

The echo statement can not be used to format numbers under bash / ksh shell. You need to use printf command to format and print data according to FORMAT.

Syntax

The syntax is:

```
printf "%'.2f" var
```

OR

```
printf "%'.2d" var
```

OR

```
printf "Total Rs.%'.2f" var
```

OR

```
printf "Total $.%'.2f" var
```

The ' act as a field and printing modifiers for decimal conversions, the thousands grouping separator is applied to the integer portion of the output according to the current LC_NUMERIC. Run the locale program to check current settings for LC_NUMERIC:

Examples

Type the following commands:

```
x="240570.578" 
printf "%'.2f\n" $x 
printf "Total $%'.2f\n" $x 
printf "Total INR.%'.2f\n" $x
```

Sample outputs:

```
2,40,570.58 
Total $2,40,570.58 
Total INR.2,40,570.58
```

Recommended readings

```
man printf
man 3 printf
man local
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution provided vi @Harini works like a charm!

```
AMOUNT=123456789
echo ${AMOUNT} | sed -e 's/..$/.&/g' | sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'

Result:
1,234,567.89
```